# Circuits by Level

Tags: computational-complexity

Context: googling existing results on Circuit Complexity.

I'm aware there are classes like AC, ACC, TC, NC, etc..

Now, suppose I have a circuit, it has the following additional program:

The circuit is divided into layers. Layer i+1 is only allowed inputs from layer i. It is not allowed inputs from layer i-1, or layer i-2, ...

What is the proper term for this restriction?

Thanks!

Comment: try the original stackoverflow 

Comment: Or rather, http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sounds like a functional composition with no feedback and limited reuse of intermediate results.  Straight-line circuit, perhaps?  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.10.04

Comment: I don't think this is off topic here, but it will certainly get better answers at cstheory.stackexchange.com

Comment: In the case of straight line programs, this property is simply referred as the SLP being "layered". 

For circuits, I am not aware of any proper term. Note that this is not a real restriction since any circuit can be layered using a few new gates. 

Comment: For circuits it's also called layered.